# Do you pluralize the word 'garment'?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, countability

For example, do you say: 'I want to buy cloth garment', or 'I want to buy cloth garments'? I more specifically would like to know the answer to cases like this, when it's getting multiple or all of something.

Comment: Do ou want to buy one item of clothing, or several? If only one, you need to include the article: *I want to buy **a** cloth garment'*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming for some reason we were using the *extremely rare* phrase *cloth garments* (only 34 hits in the iWeb corpus), it would be either *a cloth garment* (if I only intended to get one item) or *cloth garments* (or *some cloth garments*).

But I don't think any native English speaker would use the word *garment* in that context: it's not a word much used in ordinary conversation, only in official documents and the like. Also *cloth garments* is a phrase that I would never expect to hear, because nearly all garments are of cloth.

The ordinary word is *clothes* (which is plural): *I want to buy some clothes*, even if you only intend to get one. If for some reason you wanted to say explicitly that it was only one item, you would normally say what kind of clothes: *I want to buy a shirt*, for example.

If for some reason you wanted to say you were getting only one but not what, you would have to say *an item of clothing* (or more colloquially) *a bit of clothing*.